# ImportError: No module named utils

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, python-module

I'm trying to import a utilities file but running into a weird error only when I run the code through a script.

When I run test.py

location: /home/amourav/Python/proj/test.py

code:

```
import os
os.chdir(r'/home/amourav/Python/')
print os.listdir(os.getcwd())
print os.getcwd()
from UTILS import *
```

The output is:

> ['UTILS_local.py','UTILS.py',  'proj', 'UTILS.pyc']
>
> /home/amourav/Python
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "UNET_2D_AUG17.py", line 11, in 
>       from UTILS import *
>   ImportError: No module named UTILS

but when I run the code through the bash terminal, it seems to work fine

```
bash-4.1$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir(r'/home/amourav/Python/')
>>> print os.listdir(os.getcwd())
```

> ['UTILS_local.py','UTILS.py',  'proj', 'UTILS.pyc']

```
>>> from UTILS import *
```

> blah blah -everything is fine- blah blah

I'm running Python 2.7.10 on a linux machine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your project looks like this:

```
+- proj
|  +- test.py
+- UTILS.py
+- ...
```

If you like to import UTILS.py, you can choose:

(1) add the path to sys.path in test.py

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))
# now you may get a problem with what I wrote below.
import UTILS
```

(2) create a package (imports only)

```
Python
+- proj
|  +- test.py
|  +- __init__.py
+- UTILS.py
+- __init__.py
+- ...
```

Now, you can write this in test.py if you `import Python.proj.test`:

```
from .. import UTILS
```

**WRONG ANSWER**

I had this error several times. I think, I remember.

Fix: do not run `test.py`, run `./test.py`.

If you have a look at `sys.path`, you can see that there is an empty string inside which is the path of the file executed.

- `test.py` adds `''` to `sys.path`
- `./test.py` adds `'.'` to `sys.path`

Imports can only be performed from `"."`, I think.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this happens?

Comment: ^^ I am trying to reproduce it but I fail. Python 2.7.12

Comment: Thought it worked for a sec but nope.  python ./test.py -> Import Error

Comment: Import works when utils file is in the same directory as test.py

Comment: Would you like to import the files in test.py from the folder below?

Comment: I would like to delete this answer as it is obviously false but then, do we loose the discussion? Edited the answer.

Comment: I must admit, I did not properly read your question before that answer.